# python mechanize: create and submit a form

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping, mechanize

I'm interfacing a website with mechanize. The website creates a custom form using javascript and submits it after creating it. How can I do the same with mechanize, namely: create a form, add the input elements same as the site's javascript does, and submit it?

Comment: Have you read this?: http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.66/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod#JavaScript

Comment: The site's javascript eventually constructs a URL with parameters and submits it to get the results. Is it not easier to work out this end stage and reconstruct that step in a straight Python script rather than try to mimic the intermediate javascript stage?

Comment: @sgallen He does not want to parse and execute js code, he wants to mimic its functionality. At least that's what I understood...

Comment: @jadkik94 Agreed. And the route that gauden discusses above is analogous to the info covered in the link that I provided. I'm not sure any help can be provided without seeing the actual site in question and the code that the OP has attempted to use.

Comment: @sgallen: why is that? it doesn't matter what the site does, specifically. i just want to create a ClientForm from some HTML i generate with python, and submit it as if the form existed on the page i opened with mechanize. it doesn't have much to do with javascript, except that the site happens to use it (and the only way to create&submit a form that isn't in the HTML in a browser is javascript). the link you provided does not give any information on how to do that, and neither do the mechanize docs, as far as i can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
br.open(URL)
res = mechanize._form.ParseString(FORM_HTML, BASE_URL)
br.form = res[1]
#continue as if the form was on the page and selected with .select_form()
br['username'] = 'foo'
br['password'] = 'bar'
br.submit()
```

`URL` is the full URL of the visited site. `BASE_URL` is the directory the URL is in. `FORM_HTML` is any HTML that has a `form` element, e.g.:

```
<form method='post' action='/login.aspx'>
    <input type='text' name='username'>
    <input type='text' name='password'>
    <input type='hidden' name='important_js_thing' value='processed_with_python TM'>
</form>
```

For some reason, `mechanize._form.ParseString` returns two forms. The first is a `GET` request to the base URL with no inputs; the second, the properly parsed form from `FORM_HTML`.

Comment: Looking at the source code, mechanize always creates a "global form" for any inputs that were not nested inside a `<form>` tag. The normal `Browser.forms` method just selects forms that are after that first index.